# Dynamic generated HTML deep linking

Tags: javascript, deep-linking

I have a problem with deep linking. I have a single page site, in which I have many small boxes and a single big boxes, that is the 'active' content. Clicking on a small box, I clear the innerHTML. Wtart an animation, the clicked become the active content, then I replace the innerHTML($('element').html('new content')) with the new content.

My question is: there is a way to deep link this process, to have:

mysite.com/firstcontent (or something similar) and have the right content active, without have to write a mega-switcher? have I to replace all with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is handled by changing the hash (test.html**#foo**) in the `window.location`.

You can do this in conjunction with the `hashchange` event and [`window.history.pushState` / `replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) You will need some sort of shim for older browsers.  There is a [jQuery plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) that will supposedly handle this for you.